# Import/ungroup EPS file to PowerPoint slide as EMF file

Tags: vba, powerpoint, slide, eclipse-emf, eps

iam trying to figure out a way to get it done, but was getting error saying Unable to import file .
seems the device epspdf is not available in ghost script current version.
is there any work-around so that i can import the EPS file into slide, basically ungroup it as EMF format into Slide using VBA code,

````
Sub ConvertEPS()
  'Declare variables for the file paths
  Dim epsFile As String
  Dim pngFile As String

  ' Set the file paths
epsFile = InputBox("Enter File path with name in A:\B\C.eps format ", "Convert EPS")
pngFile = InputBox("Similarly enter Path to save EMF ", "Temp")

  ' Call GS to convert the EPS file to PNG
  Shell "gswin64c -sDEVICE=epspdf -o " & emfFile & " " & epsFile, vbHide

  ' Insert the emf image into the active slide
  
  ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture emfFile, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0


  ' Clean up by deleting the PNG file
  Kill pngFile

End Sub```
````

Comment: After running this, have you checked to see whether the output file does, in fact, exist?  Quite possibly it does, but your AddPicture line is executing while gswin is still waking up, so at *that* point, the EMF file hasn't yet been created.  You'll need to add delay, perhaps by polling for the existence and size of the EMF file; once it exists and stops changing size, you're ok to try inserting it.

Comment: Never heard of an epspdf device in Ghostscript. If you want an EPS turned into a PDF file you need to use the pdfwrite device, and you just send the EPS file to GS as the input. You might want to set -dEPSCrop.

Comment: @steve i tried adding the delay upto 5 mins, for the script to convert, but no use, the emf file is not getting created in the folder.

Comment: @arifhussain Have you tried manually entering the gswin command at the command prompt to verify that it does actually work and produce the EMF you're after?